# Callback method isn't executing

Tags: lightning-aura-components, query, lightning-button

My callback method isn't executing when trying to run multiple helper functions in a single controller method.

-----------------------------------------------------------------Solved--------------------------------------------------

My problem with the callback not executing was that I was not using proper quotes. I was using ( ' ' ) instead of ( " " ), rookie mistake, be sure to check this first.

With the buttons not working properly, I needed to created more than one attribute for each button otherwise each button would be set to the same value.

I have updated code below. It should work.Thanks for all the help.

Lightning:

```
<aura:component controller="PropertyPDFController" implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId" access="global" >

<aura:attribute name="searchResult" type="List"/>
<aura:attribute name="searchString" type="String" />     
<aura:attribute name="Message" type="boolean" default="false"/>     
<aura:attribute name="id" type="object"/>

<!--/////////////////////////////////Gray Buttons/////////////////////////-->

<aura:attribute name="isDisabled1" type="Boolean" default="true"/>
<aura:attribute name="isDisabled2" type="Boolean" default="true"/>
<aura:attribute name="isDisabled3" type="Boolean" default="true"/>
<aura:attribute name="isDisabled4" type="Boolean" default="true"/>
<aura:attribute name="isDisabled5" type="Boolean" default="true"/>


<table class="slds-table slds-table_bordered slds-table_striped slds-table_fixed-layout">
 <lightning:accordion aura:id ="accordion" onsectiontoggle="{!c.grayButtons}">
    <aura:iteration items="{!v.searchResult}" var="property">  
      <lightning:accordionSection name="propertyName" label="{!property.Name}">
        <!--section body-->
                  <tr>
                    <td>
                        <lightning:button
                            aura:id="ten"
                            label="10%"
                            iconName="utility:open"
                            iconPosition="left"
                            variant="neutral"
                            type="submit"
                            onclick="{!c.ten}"
                            value="{!property.Name}"
                            disabled="{!v.isDisabled1}"
                          /></td>
                    <td>
                        <lightning:button
                            aura:id="twentyFive"
                            label="25%"
                            iconName="utility:open"
                            iconPosition="left"
                            variant="neutral"
                            type="submit"
                            onclick="{!c.twentyFive}"
                            value="{!property.Name}"
                            disabled="{!v.isDisabled2}"
                          /></td>
                    <td>      
                        <lightning:button
                           aura:id="fiftyBelow"
                           label="⇩ 50% "
                           iconName="utility:open"
                           iconPosition="left"
                           variant="neutral"
                           type="submit"
                           onclick="{!c.fiftyBelow}"
                           value="{!property.Name}"
                           disabled="{!v.isDisabled3}"
                        /></td>
                    <td>      
                        <lightning:button
                           aura:id="fiftyAbove"
                           label="⇧ 50% "
                           iconName="utility:open"
                           iconPosition="left"
                           variant="neutral"
                           type="submit"
                           onclick="{!c.fiftyAbove}"
                           value="{!property.Name}"
                           disabled="{!v.isDisabled4}"
                        /></td>
                </tr>
        </lightning:accordionSection>
      </aura:iteration>
    </lightning:accordion>
  </table>
</aura:component>
```

Controller

```
grayButtons: function(component, event, helper)
    {
        helper.ten(component, event);
        helper.twentyFive(component, event);
    },
```

Update helper:

```
 ten: function(component, event)
    {
        var action = component.get("c.tenPercent");
        var myId = component.find("accordion").get("v.activeSectionName");
        action.setParams({"ten" : myId});
        action.setCallback(this, function(response)
         {
           var state = response.getState();
           if(state === "SUCCESS")              
           {
            var storeResponse = response.getReturnValue();
               if (response.getReturnValue().length != 0) {
                    component.set("v.isDisabled1", "false");
                } else {
                    component.set("v.isDisabled1", "true");

                }

           } else {
                    alert("Unknown error");
                }
       });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);       
      },
```

Apex

```
public class PropertyPDFController
{


      @AuraEnabled

        public static List <Opportunity> ten(String one) 
        {
            List <opportunity> hipdeals = new List<opportunity>();  
            String var = '012d0000000Szws';
            String otherattr = one;
            system.debug(otherattr);
            hipdeals = [select name, id from opportunity where name=:otherattr];
            return hipdeals;
        }

    @AuraEnabled 

        public static List <Opportunity> twentyFive(String one) 
        {
            List <opportunity> hipdeals = new List<opportunity>();
            String var = '012d0000000Szws';
            String otherattr = one;
            system.debug(otherattr);
            hipdeals = [//same as ten};  

            return hipdeals; 
        }    
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97953/discussion-on-question-by-tyler-callback-method-isnt-executing).

Comment: Just helping to tidy up and ensure that future readers understand the value here. @Tyler, you're very welcome to answer your own question with the solution you've discovered, and you can accept your own answer too. That creates a lasting artifact for future learners - thank you!

Comment: The pair of original question + complete solution is the most helpful to future readers and askers.

Answer (score 1):

Based on our conversation, I have put together a sample Aura component that enables/disables a Lightning button. Here it is:

SimpleButton.cmp

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global" controller="SimpleButtonCtrl">

<aura:attribute name="cons" type="List" />
   <aura:attribute name="isDisabled" type="Boolean" default="false" />
   <lightning:button aura:id="button"
                  label="Click Here"
                  iconPosition="left"
                  type="submit"
                  disabled="{!v.isDisabled}"/>
   <lightning:button aura:id="button"
                  label="Click me to Disable"
                  iconPosition="left"
                  type="submit"
                  disabled="false"
                  onclick="{!c.handleClick}"/>
</aura:component>
```

SimpleButton.js

```
({
  handleClick : function(component, event, helper) {
    var action = component.get("c.getContacts");
    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var state = response.getState();
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {
            if(response.getReturnValue().length != 0){
                component.set("v.isDisabled", "false");
            } else {
                alert("Contacts list is empty.");
                component.set("v.isDisabled", "true");
            }
        } else {
            console.log("Error in the callback");
        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
  }
})
```

SimpleButtonCtrl.apxc

```
public class SimpleButtonCtrl {
  @AuraEnabled
  public static List<Contact> getContacts(){
    List<Contact> contacts = 
            [SELECT Id, Name, MailingStreet, Phone, Email, LeadSource FROM Contact WHERE CreatedDate = : System.today()];
    System.debug('Contacts count: ' +contacts.Size());
    return contacts;
  }
}
```

This works as per your initial requirement: Enable/disable Lightning button if the query returns zero records. Just make sure to reference the Aura Boolean variable in the right context.

---

**Update**: *Automatic enable/disable button on Component load*

SimpleButton.cmp

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global" controller="SimpleButtonCtrl">
   <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
   <aura:attribute name="isDisabled" type="Boolean" default="false" />
   <lightning:button
                  aura:id="button"
                  label="Button"
                  iconPosition="left"
                  type="submit"
                  disabled="{!v.isDisabled}"/>
</aura:component>
```

SimpleButton.js

```
({
  doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
    var action = component.get("c.getContacts");
    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var state = response.getState();
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {
            if(response.getReturnValue().length != 0){
                component.set("v.isDisabled", "false");
            } else {
                alert("Contacts list is empty.");
                component.set("v.isDisabled", "true");
            }
        } else {
            console.log("Error in the callback");
        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
  }
})
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97512/discussion-between-arnold-jr-and-tyler).